# How does one force pandas 1.0.3 to write csv encoded as UTF-8 when running on Windows?

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, utf-8

Pandas 1.0.3

Python 3.7.6

code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'uom': ['M³']})
with open('encoded.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    df.to_csv(csv_file, index=False, line_terminator='\n', encoding='utf-8')

with open('encoded.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    print(csv_file.read())
```

When I run this on my mac, it works fine, echoing out the csv showing cubic meters as the unit of measurement:

```
uom
M³
```

But when running on windows, it fails trying to read the file that was written:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 7: invalid start byte
```

Instead, it seems that df.to_csv **ignored** my request to encode it as utf-8, and rather wrote it as iso-8859-1.  This works in windows to read the file:

```
>>> csv_file = open('encoded.csv', 'r', encoding='iso-8859-1')
>>> print(csv_file.read())
uom
M³
```

How does one force pandas 1.0.3 to write csv encoded as UTF-8 when running on Windows?

Comment: you opened the file to write without `encoding='utf-8'`? Also, what's wrong with `df.to_csv('path_to_file.csv', encoding='utf-8'`?

Comment: Note also: You don't need to use the `with open(...` context manager for `to_csv`, unless you're also doing something else with the file pandas handles the context on its own

Comment: @G.Anderson yes I was doing something else with the file, but I boiled it down to this more simplistic version for posting here.  Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Quang Hoang, you were correct.  Opening the file with encoding utf-8 in the first place worked:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'uom': ['M³']})
with open('encoded.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    df.to_csv(csv_file, index=False, line_terminator='\n')

with open('encoded.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    print(csv_file.read())
```

It looks like pandas only pays attention to the `encoding` parameter if you let it create the file for you, but in my case I was creating the file first.

Makes sense.